# How to emulate/replace OpenGL version?

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, opengl, mesa

Recently bought Saints Row 4 for Linux. But it needs OpenGL 4.1, when my graphics card(ATI 5470 Mobilty Graphics) haves 3.3.
My notebook is running now Ubuntu 16.04.1, Mesa from Padoka PPA. I tried to replace OpenGL version:

```
export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.1COMPAT
export MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=410
```

Then i launched Steam and took black screen with sound when game works.
Also i tried

```
export LANG=C
export LC_NUMERIC=POSIX
export force_s3tc_enable=true
```

But it has no effect too.
Notebook Lenovo G565 with AMD processor, Ubuntu 16.04.1 with Mesa from Padoka PPA.
How to run game on OpenGL 3.3 without black screen? With bugs, glitches, but without black screen.
Thanks.

Comment: assure you have latest graphics drivers installed

Comment: @ScottStensland It appears that the radeon drivers do not support newer OpenGL on this chipset, and fglrx is not usable on 16.04, nor does amdgpu support this chipset. So ironically, one would actually need to "downgrade" to Ubuntu 14.04 with fglrx drivers, in this case.

Comment: maybe VirtualGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fake it. If your hardware only supports 3.3 and the software needs 4.1, you will have to get new hardware to use that software, or you'll have to force software rendering, which will be extremely slow.

Try `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` to force software rendering.

It seems however that your card should support OpenGL 4.4, however it appears the radeon driver does not support that version for your card. Another option would be to revert to ubuntu 14.04 LTS (no newer than 14.04.4), and use the *fglrx* proprietary driver, which should enable you to use the full capability of the hardware you have.

Comment: Game crashing when i trying to start new game(but menu haves black screen)